# Sum of two time field values in transformer, Datastage

Tags: datastage

How can I take sum of two time data type field values in transformer in datastage?

**For example:** 
In one record, value is: `00:59:59` and in the 2nd record, value is: `00:10:10`. Now I want output as `01:09:09`.

Could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: I created few stage variables, which uses MinFromTime,HoursFromTime and SecondsFromTime functions so that when first record comes these variables will store 00, 59, 59 respectively.. Then I tried to write a condition If sum of seconds is > 60 then... I am stuck.. Not getting what to do.. Thanks for ur comment..If u know the solution, could u plz help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time can be converted to seconds by MidnightSecondsFromTime

```
MidnightSecondsFromTime("00:59:59")
```

do this for both times and sum the results.
Then covert it back with the DataStage functionality TimeFromMidnightSeconds

```
TimeFromMidnightSeconds("240")
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael. I finished this task by using "SecondsFromTime(), MinutesFromTime(), HoursFromTime()" functions in transformer..

Answer (score 0):

I took minuetsfromtime and secondsfromtime and hoursfromtime functions; saved in stage variables then did addition and then got the required output.